# How to put distribute array into arrays of arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to node js/express. I'm having the problem cause I need to insert bulk in MySQL. I use body-parser, but to simplify my code this is the analogy.

I have two objects from `req.body`:

```
Numbers = { 1, 2, 3 }
Letters = { a, b, c }
```

Then, I need it to be like this,

```
Object = [ { '1', 'a' }, { '2', 'b' }, { '3', 'c' } ]
```

What can I use to do this?

Comment: The expected output is wrong

Comment: How bout now? Can you help me? Please

Comment: This `Numbers = { 1, 2, 3 }
Letters = { a, b, c }` is also wrong

Comment: These can be arrays, not objects as there is no index. Object need index

Comment: What do you guys recommend to merge arrays? Please. Im pretty desparate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Numbers = [1, 2, 3]
const Letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const result = []

Numbers.forEach((el, i) => {
  result.push({[el]: Letters[i]})
})

console.log(result)
```

or

```js
const Numbers = [1, 2, 3]
const Letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const result = Numbers.map((el, i) => ({[el]: Letters[i]}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can I push more than one element?

Comment: Show an example, please

Comment: Im trying to make an array using variables and arrays. I dont know why it is not working. Please help me.

Heres my code:

var productno = req.params.id
var productslug = rows[0].product_slug
var sizeslug = req.body.sizeslug
var sizename = req.body.sizename
var initialstock = req.body.initialstock
var stock = [];

for (var x = 0; x > sizeslug.length; x++) {
 var productsku = productslug + sizeslug[x]
 var slug = sizeslug[x]
 var name = sizename[x]
 var initstock = initialstock[x]    var zero = 0
 stock.push({productsku, productno, slug, name, initstock, initstock, zero});
}

Comment: When I use console.log(stock); it doesnt contain anything.